# Unable to Parse the data from JSON response

Tags: arrays, json, web-services

I am getting below response from my web service.

```
{"d":"[{'status':false,'message':'Invalid Username or Password'}]"}
```

I want to parse the data from this response. I tried below methods to parse from console, but I can't do. Please help me.

```
var res = {"d":"[{'status':false,'message':'Invalid Username or Password'}]"};
undefined
console.log(res);
VM227:2 Object {d: "[{'status':false,'message':'Invalid Username or Password'}]"}
undefined
console.log(res.d);
VM270:2 [{'status':false,'message':'Invalid Username or Password'}]
undefined
console.log(res.d[0].status)
VM310:2 undefined
undefined
console.log(res.d[0]["status"])
VM311:2 undefined
undefined
```

Comment: as i understand, your _d_ have value _string_ so you need parse it with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: thank you @Grundy, after parsing the "d" value its working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
var a = {"d":"[{'status':false,'message':'Invalid Username or Password'}]"};
a.d = JSON.parse(a.d.replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

`a` should reference a valid JSON object now.